# Meaning 良しとしましょう?

Tags: grammar

> 良しとしましょう

I'm confused. What that mean?

Comment: I know what it means but you could have easily looked it up yourself by changing the verb しましょう into its dictionary form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[良]{よ}しとしましょう can mean:

"Let's call it good enough!",

"We will let well enough alone.",

"It could be worse.",

etc.